# Access routes in rails middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, middleware

How do I access Rails.application.routes in a Rails middleware?
I think that usually the routes.rb is being processed higher in the stack, that's why I don't have a real access to it. How can I access my routes anyhow?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your piece of middleware that requires knowledge of rails routes?

Comment: I want to enhance Rack Attack (https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack), by adding a routes directives, in the routes.rb, for describing how to protect each path. The idea is to add the metadata in the routes.rb file, and that the Rack Attack gem will automatically generate the right throttles, based on the information exists in the routes file. That way it will be much more efficient, and consistent. So when you add a new path to the routes file, it will be automatically protected. I need to be able to programmatically parse/process the routes file.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a legit rationale. While I personally don't know how to achieve this, maybe someone does.

Comment: Okay, I've created a solution. Works like charm, but I can't post it, because for some reason stackoverflow decided not to accept solutions from my account... Shame.

Comment: @NadavB we're looking for the same thing.  Can you post your solution somewhere on github or gist?  Thanks!

Comment: @lacostenycoder, I posted it here as an answer. I hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my solution, how to annotate the routes file, so I can access it in my middleware (in this example the Rack Attack)

```
  file = File.read(File.expand_path('../../routes.rb', __FILE__))
  file = file.split("\n")[1..-2].join("\n") # remove first line and last line

  myroutes = Rails.application.routes
  myroutes.prepend do
    eval(file)
  end
  myroutes.clear!
  counter = 0
  myroutes.named_routes.routes.each do |route| # For each route
    extractedroute = route[1]
    if extractedroute.defaults[:attackip] != nil
      attack = extractedroute.defaults[:attackip]
      path   = extractedroute.path.spec.left.to_s  
      attack.each do |method| # For each Attack method
        counter = counter + 1
        if method[:t] != nil # If we have a throttle
          throttlename = 'throttle-'+counter.to_s+'-'+path
          Rails.logger.error 'Creating throttle: '+throttlename
          throttle(throttlename, :limit => method[:t][0], :period => method[:t][1]) do |req|
            if req.path.start_with?(path)
                req.ip
            end
          end    
        elsif method[:a] != nil
          allow2banname = 'allow2banname-'+counter.to_s+'-'+path
          Rails.logger.error 'Creating allow2ban: '+allow2banname
          Rack::Attack.blacklist(allow2banname) do |req|

            Rack::Attack::Allow2Ban.filter(allow2banname+req.ip, :maxretry => method[:a][0], :findtime => method[:a][1], :bantime => method[:a][2]) do    
              if req.path.start_with?(path) 
                true   
              end  
            end
          end
         end

      end # For all attack mechanisms
    end # If we have an attack directive
  end # EOF for all routes
  myroutes.prepend.clear
```